# Deploying artifacts to Artifactory in a generic Jenkins project

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am using the `Jenkins Matrix plugin` to create three different kinds of builds (dev,release,manufacturing).  Each type of build has its own `artifactory repository`.

Is there a way to configure the `Jenkins Artifactory plugin` to deploy the artifacts to a different repository depending on a condition? (ie. the type of matrix build).

Currently I only see the option to deploy to a single repository.
My project is a generic project that builds a tar.gz file using a groovy script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would seem to be a shortcoming of the plugin [HAP-568](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-568)

> Currently there is only the ability to deploy to a single Artifactory
>   repository from a Jenkins CI job. It would be nice to have the ability
>   to deploy separate artifacts to multiple repositories from the same
>   Jenkins CI job. It would be even better if these multiple repos don't
>   need to be on the same server, but that would only be a nice-to-have.
>   An example would be a Jenkins CI job that builds souce that outputs
>   both debian, yum, and pypi. It needs to deploy each to separate
>   Artifactory repositories.

As a work around you can push to artifactory with curl

```
curl -u <user>:<password> -s  -X PUT \
     --data-binary @<file> http://<artifactory-server>/<directory>/<file>
```

Comment: Thanks KCACO.  Too bad it's not a standard feature.